# How to show all supported login options in Gitkit when a Gmail address is used to sign up?

Tags: web-applications, authentication, federated-identity, google-identity-toolkit

I am trying to implement Google Identity Toolkit (Gitkit) based login in my webapp. I have supplied the following sign-in options in the sign-in widget configuration: `signInOptions: ["google", "password"]`.

Now if I enter a Gmail address to sign up, the widget only shows the 'Sign in with Google' option and not the password based sign-up. If the email address is of any other domain, both password and Google based login options are shown.

How can I offer the same choice to users who use their Gmail addresses to sign up?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called Fast Email Verification. You can learn more about it here: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/federated-login

Comment: Yup, I know about the fast email verification but it should have only skipped asking the Gmail access permission, right? But it seems that even the page asking for choice between Google sign in and password based login is being skipped.